# error:invalid type argument of '->'(have 'Queue {aka struct Queue}

Tags: c

I'm trying read a file with this format instance|instruction...
like this 1 01 01 12 12 33, where the first number is the instance and after that is the numbers of the instruction.
Each line has it own id. so in that example that line if was the first one the id was 1, and the next line 2, and so on.

What I'm trying to do is group that information by a struct like the PCB struct I have. Each line has an id, and a queue where I store each number of the instruction part.

I have a struct where i have some variables and a queue inside it. The problem is the queue is not working.

```
typedef struct Queue
{
  int sizeQueue;
  int limit;
  Node *head;


}Queue;

typedef struct PCB
{
 int id;
 int program_counter;
 int size;
 Queue pointer_instrucoes;
 int instante;

}PCB;

typedef struct Node
{
 PCB *element;
 Node *next;

}Node;
```

And in the main I'm calling the struct with the queue to store some values.

```
PCB *p=new_pcb(contador);
....
p->pointer_instrucoes->head=atoi(s2); //s2 is the some number of the //instruction
```

but I'm getting this error:invalid type argument of '->'(have 'Queue {aka struct Queue}

MVCE:

main file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h> //para o output
#include "queue2.h"

int le_ficheiro(char* filename) {
FILE *ficheiro=fopen(filename,"r");
size_t len=0;
char *line=NULL;
ssize_t read;
char *s1;//string antes do primeiro espaço
char *s2;//string depois do primeiro espaço
char *sp; //linha toda
if(ficheiro==NULL) {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int contador=1; //onde comeca o id

while((read = getline (&line, &len,ficheiro))!=-1)   //le de linha a linha
{
    PCB *p=new_pcb(contador);
    sp=strchr(line,' ');
    if(!sp)
    {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    s1=strndup(line,sp-line);
    s2=sp+1;
    p->instante=atoi(s1); //converte char to int

    printf("Instante: %d\n",p->instante);
    printf("Id: %d\n",p->id);

    p.pointer_instrucoes.head=atoi(s2);

    printf("%d\n",p->pointer_instrucoes->head);



    printf("Retrieved line of length %zu:\n",read);
    printf("%s\n",s2);
    printf("Aqui : %c\n",line[0]);
    contador++;
}
 fclose(ficheiro);
 if(line)
    free(line);
    free(s1);
 exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

 }


int main()
{
  char name[50];
  printf("Name of the file: ");
  scanf("%s",name);
  le_ficheiro(name);
  return 0;
```

}

queue2.h file

```
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef struct PCB PCB;
typedef struct Node Node;
typedef struct Queue Queue;
typedef struct Queue
{
  int sizeQueue;
  int limit;
  Node *head;


 }Queue;
typedef struct PCB
{
  int id;
  int program_counter;
  int size;
  Queue pointer_instrucoes;
  int instante;

 }PCB;

 typedef struct Node
 {
  PCB *element;
  Node *next;

  }Node;

 PCB * new_pcb(int id); 
 Node * new_node(PCB * e);
 Queue * new_queue(int limit);
```

Queue2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "queue2.h"


Node * new_node(PCB * e)
 {
  Node *n=malloc(sizeof(Node));
  n->element=e;
  n->next=NULL;
  return n;
  }




Queue * new_queue(int limit)
{
   Queue *q=malloc(sizeof(Queue));
   q->limit=limit;
   q->head=NULL;
   q->sizeQueue=0;

   return q;

     }

   PCB * new_pcb(int id)
{
   PCB *p = malloc(sizeof(PCB));
   p->id=id;
   p->pointer_instrucoes=0;
   p->program_counter=0;
   p->size=0;
   return p;
   }
```

Example of input: 
1 01 02 03 04 05

2 01 02 03 02 11

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170704/discussion-between-toshiyuki-and-david-c-rankin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problems are rudimentary, and you need to spend time competing `le_ficheiro`. For starters, you cannot assign the result of `atoi(s2)` to `p.pointer_instrucoes.head`. `head` is not an `int`, it is a *pointer to* `Node*`. You violate the *Strict Aliasing Rule* [C11 Standard - §6.5 Expressions (p6,7)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5p6) and probably a dozen others in attempting to access and modify `Node*` by assigning an `int` as its value.

You invoke *Undefined Behavior* attempting to access `p->id` when it is indeterminate (uninitialized).

You make life much more difficult than it needs to be by attempting to manually separate values from `line` using `strchr(line, ' ')`. You already have all values contained in `line`, you can use `sscanf` to parse all six values to `int` in a single call and validate the line, e.g.

```
    while ((read = getline (&line, &len,ficheiro)) != -1) //le de linha a linha
    {
        int a, b, c, d, e, f;
        if (sscanf (line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", 
                    &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f) != 6) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to parse line '%d'.\n",
                    contador);
            continue;
        }
        PCB *p = new_pcb (contador);
        if (!p)  /* Validate EVERY Allocation */
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
```

However, before you can validate every allocation and avoid potentially invoking *Undefined Behavior*, you must provide meaningful return values from `new_node, new_queue & new_pcb`, to indicate success/failure, e.g.

```
Node *new_node (PCB *e)
{
    Node *n = malloc (sizeof *n);
    if (!n) {   /* Validate EVERY Allocation */
        perror ("malloc-new_node");
        return NULL;  /* return NULL on failure */
    }
    n->element = e;
    n->next = NULL;

    return n;
}

Queue *new_queue (int limit)
{
    Queue *q = malloc (sizeof *q);   /* typo in declaration */
    if (!q) {
        perror ("malloc-new_queue");
        return NULL;
    }
    q->limit = limit;
    q->head = NULL;
    q->sizeQueue = 0;

    return q;
}

PCB *new_pcb (int id)
{
    PCB *p = malloc (sizeof *p);
    if (!p) {
        perror ("malloc-new_pcb");
        return NULL;
    }
    p->id = id;
    p->pointer_instrucoes = 0;
    p->program_counter = 0;
    p->size = 0;

    return p;
}
```

It is clear you got part way through `le_ficheiro` and just gave up. It isn't anywhere near complete, only 1 of the data values from each line of input was even used in your code (the rest you attempted to print as text just to see where your `s2` pointer was pointing -- but not make any further or meaningful use of the values)

You don't even call `new_node` in order to create a `Node*` value that conceivably could be assigned to `p.pointer_instrucoes.head`. Take it step-by-step. You need to call `new_node` somewhere in `le_ficheiro` so that you have a pointer you can assign to `p.pointer_instrucoes.head`. There isn't any magic to it, but you must be methodical about insuring each value and each member of each structure is created and properly initialized with a value before you attempt to use them.

Basically you had a shell for `le_ficheiro` which you need to continue to complete, working from a somewhat better starting position of:

```
int le_ficheiro (char* filename) 
{
    FILE *ficheiro = fopen (filename,"r");
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read = 0;
    int contador = 1;   //onde comeca o id

    if (ficheiro == NULL) {
        perror ("fopen-filename");
        exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((read = getline (&line, &len,ficheiro)) != -1) //le de linha a linha
    {
        int a, b, c, d, e, f;
        if (sscanf (line, "%d %d %d %d %d %d", 
                    &a, &b, &c, &d, &e, &f) != 6) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: failed to parse line '%d'.\n",
                    contador);
            continue;
        }
        PCB *p = new_pcb (contador);
        if (!p)
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

        p->instante = a;
        printf ("Instante: %d\n", p->instante);

        /* you must assign and allocate as necessary to use remaining
         * values read from file HERE. Nowhere do you assign p->id
         * before attempting to print, etc...
         */
        printf ("Id: %d\n", p->id);

        /* you cannot assign atoi(s2) to p.pointer_instrucoes.head.
         * it expects type 'Node *', not int.
         */
        // p.pointer_instrucoes.head = FIXME;
        // printf ("%d\n", p->pointer_instrucoes->head);
        contador++;
    }
    fclose(ficheiro);

    free (line);
    free(s1);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When you are stuck in writing a function, don't give up. Instead see [**How to debug small programs**](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and talk to the duck... Really, it helps `:)`